# Can I assign a category to more than one section in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I want to assign the same category to multiple sections in Joomla. E.g. category *cats* will be child of the sections *domestic-animals* and *adorable-anmials*.

Is there a component or a trick to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching all the functions that deal with section-category relationships and dirty-add this case there.

However I would not recommend doing this type of Joomla core hacking because you would need to keep track of all such hacks during core updates.

What do you want to accomplish? I guess there should be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

No, in Joomla! 1.0 and 1.5, category cannot be assigned to multiple sections. 
To tackle that you may do the following

```
* creating duplicate articles of the categories you want and assign the duplicates articles to new category and then assign it to the section. so that the article copy will there be in two categories under same section
* using menus rather than dynamic lists of content items. so that with the menu structure you can work out the thing you need
* using various third party extensions that simulate assignment to multiple categories to same section.
* using key words to simulate categories and sections.
```

if you can explain me what you are exactly about to do. then i shall make it more specific

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias to make cats as sections domestic-animals and adorable-animals.

If you want to make field that can assign multiple category you have to make edit the core code.